# C++ - Copy keys of one map to other

Tags: c++, key-value, stdmap

I have something like this -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main() {
  
  std::map<std::string, int> size = {
    {"a", 1},
    {"b", 2},
    {"c", 3}
  };

  std::map<std::string, void*> ptr;
  auto it1 = size.cbegin();
  auto it2 = ptr.cbegin();
  while(it1 != size.cend()) {
    it2->first = it1->first; //error
    it1++;
    it2++
  }
}
```

I want to copy just the keys of the map size to map ptr before adding the values in map ptr. How can I do that?

Edit: I tried loops but itgives error

Comment: Is there an issue with simply writing a `for` loop?  If you have tried a `for` loop, where did it fail?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie A `for` loop does work but I am looking for something more concise, like in Python where I can copy the keys and fill the values in just one statement. Is something like this possible in C++?

Comment: Just as a warning, do not use Python or any other language as a model in writing C++ code.  If you continue to go down this path, your C++ programs will 1) Be buggy,  2) Be inefficient, and 3) Look weird to a C++ programmer.

Comment: Note that there is no automatic syntax in C++ to do this.  Both `map` types are different types, regardless of what the keys are.  You will have to write some kind of a loop, or use `std::for_each`, or `std::transform` or similar function.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I edited the code with loops but there is error. Can you have a look?

Comment: Erm, if you want a non-const iterator, use `begin`, not `cbegin`

Comment: Your problem is that your `ptr.cbegin` is equal to `ptr.cend()` because you don't have any element in your `ptr` map yet. Be careful to not access positions like `end()` or `cend()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `ptr.cbegin` is equal to `ptr.cend()` because you don't have any element in your `ptr` map yet. Thus you need to create those elements. Additionally if you want to `mutate` `it1` by `incrementing` it, then you should use `begin()` instead of `cbegin` which returns a `const-pointer`.

You can also transform the second `map` into an `unordered_map` for better performance, since you don't need the elements to be ordered for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
  
  std::map<std::string, int> size = {
    {"a", 1},
    {"b", 2},
    {"c", 3}
  };

  std::unordered_map<std::string, void*> ptr;
  auto it1 = size.begin();
  
  std::cout << (ptr.cbegin() == ptr.cend());

  while(it1 != size.cend()) {
    ptr[it1->first] = nullptr; //error
    it1++;
  }
}
```

Note: Consider using a `smart pointer` for your `void*` unless you really really need it.

Answer (score -1):

You can iterate over the keys of `size` with

```
std::for_each(std::cbegin(size), std::cend(size), [&](const std::pair<std::string, int> &pair) { /* in here, "pair.first" accesses each key */ }
```

That said, it is never necessary nor wise to declare a variable `void *` in C++.  Anything can decay to a `void *`.

Comment: Actually, I needed it for my use case. Thanks for helping.